# Конструкция new Function

Tags: javascript

Сейчас изучаю Js по учебнику https://learn.javascript.ru.

Вопрос по функциям:

```
var sum = new Function('a,b', ' return a+b; ');
var result = sum(1, 2);
alert( result ); // 3
```

То есть, функция создаётся вызовом new Function(params, code):

params
Параметры функции через запятую в виде строки.
code
Код функции в виде строки.
Таким образом можно конструировать функцию, код которой неизвестен на момент написания программы, но строка с ним генерируется или подгружается динамически во время её выполнения.

Я не понял, как код функции неизвестен на момент написания программы, если во втором параметре указано `' return a+b; '`? Или имеется в виду, что можно оставить данный параметр пустым, ''?

Comment: строку тела функции можно составить динамически

Comment: @Grundy , можете привести, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в данном случае в качестве тела функции передается обычная строка, до передачи она может быть собрана как угодно, на основании переменных, значение которых неизвестно в момент написания.

Например:

```js
function calc(x, expr) {
  var func = new Function('x', `return ${expr}`);
  console.log(func(x));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="expr" value="x*x" /> <br/>
<input type="text" id="x" value="2" /> <br/>
<button onclick="calc(x.value, expr.value)">Calc</button>
```